# Saving json in html li in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to make a component capable of autosuggesting values based
on an online API, and then return the value and associated json to
my parent component.

For now, I'm able to generate a list of autosuggested values on the fly
and when one is selected and submited by the user, to update the state
of ma parent component.
However, i'm not able to get the complete json of the autosuggested value
since I lost it when building my list.

How can I have a list of readable names built by react, but still being able to save the complete json info when submitting ?

see:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-autocomplete-module-g79ju?fontsize=14

Thx :)

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself, not just on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API calls are not working (401 Unauthorized), but you need to add the data as well as the id.

Start with changing to:

```
onClick={e => this.onClick(e, optionName)}
```

and you can access the optionName object as the second argument of the onClick method.